# AWS associate IP with instance in other account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I have a problem that I'm trying to fix for my school project.

Let's say I have account A and my friend accounts B.

Each one of us as 1 instance ubuntu, and I want to transfer/allocate my elastic ip (if a program fails) to his instance through AWS CLI.

Both instances are in the same vpc, same subnet.

so I have a script that disassociates the elastic ip and associates the new one to his instance like this.

```
aws ec2 disassociate-address --public-ip 00.00.000.00
```

(maybe on the script here I have to transfer the elastic ip or make the AWS CLI access his account?)

```
aws ec2 associate-address --public-ip 00.00.000.00 --instance-id i-00000000
```

Of course, it won't work because the AWS CLI is connected to my account but I can't seem to find a way to make this work.

Possible ways, transfer ip but don't know how to do it in an automated way, IAM roles.

Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: You can [transfer Elastic IP addresses between AWS accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/10/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-vpc-transfer-elastic-ip-addresses-between-aws-accounts/). See more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-eips.html#transfer-EIPs-intro). Afaik this is not something that you can do quickly through automation as the receiving account needs to accept the transfer so it may not be a viable solution for your use case.

Comment: Also, consider [DNS failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html).

Comment: I saw that, but don't know how to implement it. like I don't mind having both instances on one account but since we are 2 I would like to take advantage of the free tier since it's our first time using aws.

Comment: You should not rely on a particular IP address. That is why DNS was invented. Use DNS to point to a different IP address.